# Creating Windows Account using C++

Tags: c++, windows, exploit

I will give a basic rundown of the situation first. I work for a game server rental company that is falling victim to an exploit inside of a major game engine (source). Basically, the developers left not one but two exploits inside the code, one to Send/Recieve files, and one that lets clients run plugins. Whats happening is clients are running plugins, uploading custom plugins to the servers, then the servers are running them, and as a result creating remote desktop accounts that these exploiters are using to access machines. (Theres actually a video on youtube of someone breaking into one of our boxes lol)

I have spent all day writing a fix for this, by blocking the SendFile() and RecieveFile() functions on the server side, however my employer has asked that while I am doing this, I use the exploit to gain access to a box he lost the password to. So I have written all of the necessary code, except I need to be able to create a temporary account much like these exploiters are doing. So any help with code on creating a windows account from c++ would be most appreciated. I have been told there are plenty of samples on Google, but apparently google skills are not up to par.

Comment: I hope you sue the developers.  Maybe have them arrested.

Comment: I believe you should make special version of code for your employer that will not be launched with the commercial versions.  Otherwise, this introduces more leaks and holes in the application.

Comment: Hmm, your boss has lost the password.  Bummer.  Sounds *really* credible.  Really.  Did the dog eat the piece of paper it was on?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [NetUserAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649(VS.85).aspx) with server name NULL (local computer). There's a nice C++ example that illustrates it on the page.